# Docker command error (repository name component must match "[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*")

Tags: docker

Why won´t this command work?

> sudo docker run --name guacamole --link guacd --link mysql \ -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db \ -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user \ -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password123 \ -d -p 8181:8080 glyptodon/guacamole

Output is:

> ```
> Unable to find image ' -e:latest' locally
>
> repository name component must match "[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*"
> ```

http://wiki.univention.com/index.php?title=Cool_Solution_-_Guacamole and http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html#guacd-docker-image have this command on their website as part of a tutorial, but it doesn´t seem to be correct?

Comment: Is that how you are actually splitting the lines?

Comment: Edit your question, remove the example command, and replace it with the command you actually used.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is the command I actually used.. (edited the password but the password was lowercase + two numbers)

Comment: @jordanm they don´t get split in the terminal if that´s what you mean, it´s one line there

Comment: @user1857116 newlines are important since white space is syntax for the shell. You shouldn't add/remove syntax when asking your question.

Comment: @jordanm I have removed the newlines in the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use backslashes "\", make sure you enter the text after that in a new line. Backslashes here are used to just split out a long command into multiple lines in the shell.

For your example, this should work for you if you wish to use backslashes.

```
$ sudo docker run --name guacamole --link guacd --link mysql \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db \
-e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password123 \
-d -p 8181:8080 glyptodon/guacamole
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem, the ´\´ shouldn´t actually be there!

> sudo docker run --name guacamole --link guacd --link mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password123 -d -p 8181:8080 glyptodon/guacamole

will work :)